# want to calculate percentage of video watched

Tags: math, video, percentage

I am developing a video gallery app in that I want to calculate the percentage of video watched.

For that I have a number of minutes of the video and total minutes watched by the user, if the user watched 10 minutes of a video twice I will save 20, and if the user watched the same video 3 times and at 3rd time he only watch for 4 minutes then I want to calculate the percentage watched for the last time.

I would like it be a like the method bellow, and I would need a formula for this.

```
function getPercentageWatched(videoTiming,totalMinWatched){}
```

Comment: I do not understand your examples. What do "for twice" and "for 3 time" mean? Perhaps you should explain in more depth, using different wording.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are running the video in a loop. So if `totalMinWatched ≥ videoTiming` the user has seen the video at least once completely, and you are interested in the remaining percentage, i.e. the last portion that isn't complete.

If you compute `totalMinWatched / videoTiming`, that quotient will have an integer part (before the decimal point) indicating the number of completed runs, and a fractional part (after the decimal point) indicating the fraction of the last partial run. That fractional part times 100 is the fraction of the current loop iteration.

```
ratio = totalMinWatched / videoTiming
fraction = ratio - floor(ratio)
percentage = 100 * fraction
```

Comment: yes thats exactly i want but i don't want last remaining portion but  the portion he has completed. and how i can verify that the percentage i got is correct.